# ¿Cómo maquetar la columnas de bootstrap para dipositivos móviles?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid

Estoy teniendo un problema con el sistema de columnas, es que ni se me rellena la pantalla ni se me oculta la columna que quiero cuando pongo la pantalla en tamaño de dispositivo móvil. Ya he probado con las dimensiones de `xl`,`lg`,`md`,`sm` y `xs` pero no me sale, así que probé por dejarlas todas sin definir tamaño y nada, tampoco funcionaba, la columna que quiero que desaparezca es la que sale de color rojo cosa que tampoco consigo usando `d-none` ni `d-md-block` y tampoco desaparecía y ya no sé que hacer.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!--    Required    meta    tags    -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1,    shrink-to-fit=
no">
    <!--    Bootstrap   CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: burlywood;">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: chartreuse;">.col-8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4" style="background-color: red;">.col-4</div>
            <div class="col-8" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                .col-8
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color: coral;">col 6</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color: coral;">col 6</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: blue;">col 4</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: blue;">col 4</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: chartreuse;">col 12</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo el -1 por esta pregunta si todo parece bien.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 tiene un modelo de **mobile first** en el cual ya no se encuentra el  *breakpoints* `xs`, pero siguen: `sm`,`md`,`lg` y `xl`, siendo todos estos:

```
.col,//media (min-width:0px)
.col-1,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-auto,
.col-sm,//@media (min-width:576px)
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-auto,
.col-md,//@media (min-width:768px)
.col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-md-auto,
.col-lg,//@media (min-width:992px)
.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-lg-auto,  
.col-xl,//@media (min-width:1200px) 
.col-xl-1,
.col-xl-10,
.col-xl-11,
.col-xl-12,
.col-xl-2,
.col-xl-3,
.col-xl-4,
.col-xl-5,
.col-xl-6,
.col-xl-7,
.col-xl-8,
.col-xl-9,
.col-xl-auto
```

Tú utilizas `col-x` siendo `x` el numero en la columna, siendo este una vista para pantallas móviles y superiores. Entonces, debes de aclarar los tamaños en cada tipo de dispositivo.

Para tu problema modifiqué las siguientes líneas:

```
<div class="col-4 d-none d-md-block" style="background-color: red;">.col-4</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-8" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
```

Indicando que la sección roja: será de tamaño 4 (`col-4`) desde dispositivos móviles, pero también indico que su `display` será `none` (`d-none`, ocultando el div) desde dispositivos móviles, pero que a partir de tabletas el `display` será `block`(`d-md-block`, mostrando el div).

Si le pones atención, también modifico el `div` hermano en dispositivos tableta.

Ademas, también añadí `jquery.3.3.1` ya que es imprescindible para algunas funcionalidades de Bootstrap.

**RESULTADO:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!--    Required    meta    tags    -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1,    shrink-to-fit=
no">
    <!--    Bootstrap   CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: burlywood;">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: chartreuse;">.col-8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 d-none d-md-block" style="background-color: red;">.col-4</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                .col-8
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color: coral;">col 6</div>
                    <div class="col-6" style="background-color: coral;">col 6</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: blue;">col 4</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-4" style="background-color: blue;">col 4</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">col 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: chartreuse;">col 12</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Para apreciar mejor los resultados debes verlo también en `pagina completa`.