# Responsividad con CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un sitio web y ahora estoy trabajando en la parte de responsividad.

```css
/* Estilos para pantallas mayores a 1340px */
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header .logo-empresa {
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header img {
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 190px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar ul li a {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar ul li a:hover {
  color: #40041d;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 1340px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1275px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 180px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1230px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 160px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 140px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1135px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1105px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1065px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 904px) {
  .header img {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 888px) {
  .nav-bar {
    margin-left: 170px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 866px) {
  .header {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .header img {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-bar ul {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav-bar ul li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="index.php" class="logo-empresa"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="nosotros.php">Nosotros</a></li>
      <li><a href="productos.php">Productos</a></li>
      <li><a href="portafolio.php">Portafolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Les pongo la parte del menú porque ahí es donde me esta dando conflicto y creo que resolviendo esa parte pues lo demás sera igual o muy parecido.

Como ven tengo definidos estilos para pantallas mayores de `1340px` pero cuando empiezo a disminuir el tamaño de la pantalla los elementos del **header** se van desajustando por lo que estoy haciendo uso de **media queries** para ajustar los elementos dependiendo del tamaño en el que se encuentre la pantalla, el inconveniente que estoy viendo es que estoy haciendo uso de muchos **media queries** por que cada que reduzco el tamaño (aunque sea por muy poco) se mueven los elementos.

Creo yo que lo ideal sería no usar tantos **media queries**, entonces la pregunta sería ¿como podría no usar tantos **media queries** o así como lo tengo esta bien?

Comment: No veo el problema, he copiado tu código y solo veo que pasa de estar los elementos en el mismo renglón a estar uno sobre otro, ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: @BetaM lo que quiero es que me digan como puedo reducir el uso de tantos media queries, por que si te fijas estoy usando muchos

Comment: en mi respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326430/c%c3%b3mo-maquetar-la-columnas-de-bootstrap-para-dipositivos-m%c3%b3viles/326455#326455 encontraras algo de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

El punto general por el cual debes comenzar es que tu diseño apunte a determinados **breakpoints**; es decir:

Tamaños mas comunes de pantallas sobre aquellos dispositivos en los cuales se visualizaría tu desarrollo web.

Tomemos como punto de referencia la [doc. oficial de Material UI](https://material-ui.com/es/customization/breakpoints/) la cual propone:

- Dispositivo pequeño y una medida de 600px
- Dispositivo mediano de 960px
- Dispositivo grande de 1280px
- Dispositivo extra grande de 1920px

Una vez que se establecen puntos de **rompimiento** en común será mas fácil:

- Identificar el flujo de los elementos ante determinadas medidas
- Reducir el número de **media queries** teniendo solo que modificar los elementos que por cada una requieran un nuevo acomodo

Lo anterior debido a que:

- Tu diseño al momento de *usarlo* funciona, sin embargo tiene demasiadas *media queries*
- Para evitar caer en opiniones tomemos como referencia lo que *otros ya saben hacer mejor*

Por otro lado y como punto extra, te recomiendo mires la implementación de **flexbox** ya que:

- Haría mas simple y fácil de manejar la maquetación de lo que quieres al momento
- En las media queries solo deberías modificar el valor de **`flex-direction`** cambiandolo de **`row`** a **`column`** para que los elementos queden uno sobre otro

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      ul {
        display: flex;
        background-color: gray;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 400px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      ul li{
        list-style: none;
        margin: 15px;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
      }
      a:hover {
        color: #40041d;
      }
    </style>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="index.php" class="logo-empresa"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
        <nav class="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="nosotros.php">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="productos.php">Productos</a></li>
                <li><a href="portafolio.php">Portafolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.php">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```